# which is the overall size of neural network data-set?

Tags: neural-network

actually, there are lots of questions about neural network data-set training size. but my problem is the overall size of data-set for neural network.
i found a data-set in here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/User+Knowledge+Modeling   which is related to user knowledge modeling subject.
this data-set have 403 instances. i want to work with ANN and ANFIS .
now my question is that whether or not this size of  data-set effects  the final result? and should i use another data-set consisting of more instances?
please pay attention my question is not about percentage of training , testing, and validating data.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm Flavio Ferrara reply, you have to keep in mind that there is always a strict relationship between the number of free parameters in your model and the size of training set. Number of free parameters (weights and bias values) in neural networks is also related to the architecture of the network.

As the number of free parameters increases, you need much more data to estimate their true values, and if you couldn't do so, the your model tend be over-fitted over the training data. 
In brief, answering the question whether your training set suffices for your model or not, is heavily related to the number of free parameters you have in your model. more parameters to be estimated, larger training set is required. In other hands, for ANNs the architecture contributes to the number of parameters.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the dataset size influences the performance of any machine learning algorithm.

Under a statistical viewpoint, with a small dataset, you may not be able to capture the statistics of the distribution you are trying to modeling. 
A more "practical" problem is that your model is likely to overfit your dataset, both the training or the test/validation set.

There is another issue here, and it's whether you are using "good" features as inputs for your neural net. Good, in this context, means features that really characterize your classes of interest.

A common approach is to **augment** your dataset. You can use [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725279/what-is-the-bootstrapped-data-in-data-mining) or apply some random transformation to your training set, but the latter is mainly use with images.